# Mongo db findOne query will not stop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, node-mongodb-native

I am using express js and angular js, but I found that the findOne method will not end.

For every request, the backend function will get the obj first before doing CURD stuff:

```
exports.article = function(req, res, next, id) {

    Article.load(id, function(err, article) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));
        req.article = article;
        next();
    });
};
```

and then get to destroy it:

```
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
    var article = req.article;

    article.remove(function(err) {
...
```

but it will never enter the destroy scope since it keeps endless running in exports.article.

the load operation is actually like this:

```
ArticleSchema.statics.load = function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).populate('user', 'name username').exec(cb);
};
```

when i modify it to:

```
exports.team = function(req, res, next, id) {
    req.team = Team.findOne({_id: id});
};
```

it did the same with endless running...please help

Answer (score 0):

I found that the next(); function should be added in the last of execution.